# Do I have to put two logins and registrations for both Customers and Suppliers sections?

Tags: uml, diagram, activity-diagram

I'm new to Activity diagrams. I was told to draw an Activity diagram for this scenario...

This is a brief description of web-based Tool Exchange Brokering Service. In order to provide match making
support, the system is to register both Suppliers and Customers. System as the ability of the system to
register a new customer with details of name, address, telephone number and email. As per customer
registrations, system can also register Tool Suppliers. The system has to generate a unique ID for each new
customer and suppliers. For registered Suppliers, they can update their tools details in a central repository
and register them under relevant category (Constructions, Gardening, Automobile, etc) on System’s
Catalogue. Once registered a customer can login and browse the tools catalogue and select the tool or
tools they wish to hire. Tools are hired out in multiples of whole days. When a tool is hired out the
catalogue displays its outstanding hire period, if a tool is not already out or booked it is displayed as
immediately available. If a customer selects an available tool the order is fulfilled, and the display is
updated. If a customer selects a tool already hired, the system puts the customer on back order and
updates the display with the additional hire period. When back orders become available for fulfilment
customers are notified by email.
Note: In addition to the above specification, you are free to make any assumption in order to complete this
course work. However, all such assumptions that you have taken are to be listed at appropriate places.

What I think I should do is, making three main sections (partitions) for System, Customers, and Suppliers. Do I have to make two different login and registrations for both Customers and Suppliers?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look in to Role Based Access Control (RBAL). In summary, to have a clean centralised source of data, you would normally have a single data store for your users. You would have another data store for the user types (e.g. supplier or customer) and another data store to distinguish capabilities (e.g. a supplier can access tool details) – the controller or business logic layer in your application would then handle the access to different sections of functionality.

There are edge cases, for example will you be expecting users to register as a supplier and a customer – but RBAL is probably a good place to start before you go into further complexity

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sir! Can I just create those three main sections and make two different logins and registrations for suppliers and customers and then go on like that? Is it wrong to do it that way?

Comment: Do you mean create two different login and registration "screens"? This would be acceptable, especially if you are asking for different data fields for each user type. However, in most cases you will still want to store all users in one unified store.